# trying to access a url from server block configuration in ngnix

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have *AWS (S3 + Cloudfront)* static website which hosts assets for me. (For example: https://assets.example.com)

I have a react app (using nginx) on an *EC2* server (For example: https://ui.example.com)

Now, I want to load an asset from (https://assets.example.com) domain to (https://ui.example.com) in `iframe` - (This is completed), but I want to tweak the HTML (via JS) of the assets from the UI code, well, that is not possible as the origin is not same (iframe.contentWindow.document.innerHTML - CORS errors out).

Hence I decided to have the same origin (https://ui.example.com)

For that, I thought that if a user hits https://ui.example.com the react app should get loaded, and if https://ui.example.com/assets is accessed then assets from https://assets.example.com should get picked.

For that, I modified the default 443 (pointing to https://ui.example.com) `server block` in nginx and added a `location` of `/assets` with `alias` of `https://assets.example.com` (This is not working), I also tried without protocol i.e. `assets.example.com` and with / without trailing slashes, non of them are working, it redirects to `error/404`.

I am not sure if I can add a domain name in alias or not, but my main goal is to modify assets (with help of JS) from the react app that is been hosted in S3 (or any other server)

Request to assist on the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can set Nginx proxy_pass configure in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled.

```
Server {

  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssk http2;
  server_name ui.example.com;

  location / {
     ....
  }
  location /assets {
    proxy_pass https://assets.example.com;
  }
}
```